# Ionic 2 internal function and external function

Tags: javascript, function, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm currently developping an application with Ionic 2 using the library BLE https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble . What I want to know here, it's I have a function connectToDevice which call the function ble.connectToDevice which call the function onConnected. Inside the function onConnected I want to call the function enableNotification(device) that is external to the function connectToDevice. But I get the error : TypeError: _this.enableCoinNotification is not a function.

Could someone solve this problem and explain it to me?

```
export class BleProvider {
 constructor(){
  this.connectToDevice(device)
 }

 connectToDevice(device){
   let onConnected = (device) => {
    console.log("Connected to device: " + device.name);
    return startNotifications(device);
  },
  onDisconnected = (device) => {
    console.log('Disconnected from device: ' + device.name);
  },
  onConnectError = (error) => {
    console.log('Connect error: ' + error);
  };

setTimeout(() => {
  ble.connectToDevice(
    device,
    onConnected,
    onDisconnected,
    onConnectError)
  }, 500);

  let startNotifications = (device) => {
    console.log("Start Notification called");
    this.enableCoinNotification(device) // ERROR : TypeError: _this.enableCoinNotification is not a function
  };
 }

  enableCoinNotification(device){

   let onNotificationSuccess = (data) =>{
    console.log('characteristic data: ' + ble.fromUtf8(data));
   },
   onNotificationError = (error) =>{
   };
  ble.enableNotification(
   device,
   this.coinEventNotificationUUID,
   onNotificationSuccess,
   onNotificationError)
   }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `connectToDevice ` ?

Comment: I can call it in the constructor, i edited the code

Comment: did the soln help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) API:

```
  let startNotifications = (device) => {
    console.log("Start Notification called");
    this.enableCoinNotification(device);
  };
  startNotifications.bind(this); // <-- Add this line
```

`this` is lost when you pass only the function definition defined by **arrow function**.

---

**Alternatively:**

Yes i agree with **@Junior**

```
ble.connectToDevice(device,
   (...arg) => onConnected(...arg),
   (...arg) => onDisconnected(...arg),
   (...arg) => onConnectError(...arg));
```

By changing the callbacks to arrow functions you can reference to the parent `this` object scope.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, your solution is good. There is also to declare all my function with the fat arrow => that will help to have this as class closure